# What is the correct way to simplify $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Let us simplify  $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$ step by step, $A \in R^{m \times n}$ matrix, $x \in R^{n \times 1}$, $b \in R^{m \times 1}$

$(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

$= (x^TA^T - b^T)(Ax - b)$ (property of transpose)

$ = x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx + b^Tb$ (distribution property)

**Now what is the correct way to combine the inner terms**

$-x^TA^Tb - b^TAx $?

or equivalently

$x^TA^Tb + b^TAx $?

**I find myself constantly asking the following questions**

- Is it legal or illegal to transpose any of the two terms? Why?
- Which term ($x^TA^Tb$ or  $b^TAx $) should you take the transpose of? Why?

I would really appreciate if someone can resolve this for me

Comment: The key point is that $ x^T A^T b $ is a scalar, as is $ b^T A x $. And these two terms are equal, because any real scalar is equal to its own transpose.

Comment: I understand that this question may have come from convex optimization, but the question itself is entirely generic and does not depend on any optimization context, so I've adjusted your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both $x^TA^Tb$ and $b^TAx$ are scalars, you can transpose any of them.

You can transpose $x^TA^Tb$ and get
$$x^TA^Tb + b^TAx = b^TAx + b^TAx = 2 b^TAx$$
or you can transpose $b^TAx$ and get
$$x^TA^Tb + b^TAx = x^TA^Tb + x^TA^Tb = 2 x^TA^Tb$$
and since both results are scalar, they are equal to their respective transposes, we get:
$$ 2 x^TA^Tb = 2 (x^TA^Tb)^T = 2 b^TAx.$$

So to summarize, you can take the transposes of either one of them, and should probably take the transpose of $x^TA^Tb$ since you will reach the simpler result $2b^TAx$ faster (it can be considered simpler since there is no transpose of $A$ in it).

Comment: Note that $A$ isn't symmetric, you must write $A^T$ in your second case.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ can have linearly independent columns only if $m\ge n$. The typical instance of this problem is where $m\gg n = \operatorname{rank} A$.  In that case, the small matrix $A^TA$ is invertiable since it's an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $n$.  The matrix $B = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ is an $m\times m$ matrix of small rank, $n$.  (If $A$ were a square matrix, then $B$ would be the identity matrix.)

**Exercise:** Prove that $b\mapsto Bb$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$.

And now on to simplifying:
\begin{align}
& (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) \\[10pt]
= {} & (Ax - Bb + Bb - b)^T(Ax - Bb + Bb - b) \\[10pt]
= {} & (Ax-Bb)^T(Ax-Bb) + \underbrace{(Ax-Bb)^T(Bb-b) + (Bb-b)^T(Ax-Bb)}_\text{This is $0$.} + (Bb-b)^T(Bb-b) \\[10pt]
= {} & (Ax-Bb)^T(Ax-Bb) + (Bb-b)^T(Bb-b).
\end{align}

In this last form, notice that $x$ can be so chosen that $Ax= Bb$, since $Bb$ is in the column space of $A$.  Indeed, that happens precisely when $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T b$.  That is the one value of $x$ that makes the first term $0$, and thus it is the one value of $x$ that mimimizes the entire quantity. Hence we see that the second term in the last line is actually the smallest possible value of the whole quantity as $x$ varies.  (If $A$ has linearly dependent columns and more rows than columns, then there is more than one value of $x$ that makes the first term in the last line vanish.)

This may be considered species of completing the square.